# How to setup Index Buffer Object

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, index-buffer

I am trying to render a basic model using lwjgl (java OpenGL binding). I am trying to do this off my own knowledge as much as possible using what I remember. I created a vbo like this:

```
    int verticesVBO = GL15.glGenBuffers ( );
    vboIDs.add ( verticesVBO );
    FloatBuffer verticesData = bufferFromData ( vertices );// Custom Method
    GL15.glBindBuffer ( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , verticesVBO );
    GL15.glBufferData ( GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , verticesData , GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);// Binds the vbo to the bound vao
    if(( error = GL11.glGetError()) != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) System.err.println(GLU.gluErrorString(error));
```

I got about this far with the index buffer object:

```
    int indicesVBO = GL15.glGenBuffers ( );
    vboIDs.add ( verticesVBO );
    IntBuffer indicesData = bufferFromData ( indices );
    GL15.glBindBuffer ( GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , indicesVBO );
    GL15.glBufferData ( GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER , indicesData , GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    //Problem Here
    if(( error = GL11.glGetError()) != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) System.err.println(GLU.gluErrorString(error));
```

The probelm I am having is that I don't know the method to use to bind the index buffer to the vao. For the vbo containing the vertex data I know to use `GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` but I remember index buffers behaving differently. This is a learning process so please be constructive with your criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is bind the index buffer while the VAO is bound.

See https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#General_use:

> `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`
>
> > All rendering functions of the form gl*Draw*Elements*​ will use the pointer field as a byte offset from the beginning of the buffer object bound to this target. The indices used for indexed rendering will be taken from the buffer object. **Note that this binding target is part of a Vertex Array Objects state, so a VAO must be bound before binding a buffer here.**

Comment: then how do you specify which attribute list to bind it too? Like when doing a regular vbo that contains normals or vertex data don't you usually specify the location in the vao using the first parameter in `GL20.glVertexAttribPointer()`? For example `GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);` would take the first slot in the vao. How do you tell OpenGL which slot that the index buffer should be bound to?

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian: There's no such thing as what you're discussing (short of a weird extension only AMD supports [`GL_AMD_interleaved_elements`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/AMD/interleaved_elements.txt)). The vertex stream pulls every attribute from the same index.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I never did any serious opengl programming but I felt almost certain that you could bind vertex data in one spot in the vao, normals in another, indices in another, textureCoords in another, etc. I was certain that was how vao's worked. If that isn't how they work than what is the point of binding multiple vbo's to one vao?

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian Index buffers aren't bound to attributes.

Comment: @immibis if that is true than that explains a lot

Comment: ok I feel like there is gaping hole in my understanding of vbos. So correct me if I am wrong but you can store any type of data in a vbo and that data doesnt have to be just vertices but can also be normal vectors and texture coordinates right?

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian Yes. You're now confusing vertex buffers with index buffers?

Comment: well I thought they were almost the same thing but slightly different. I think what is really confusing me is that both ibo and vbo are generated using GL15.glGenBuffers ( );

Comment: so I thought they were the same thing

Comment: ok never mind I thought the way I did it in the past was that each individual model had a vao containing all of its data but I just looked at how I did it in the past and actually each Model object holds an vao and indices data seperatly

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian glGenBuffers generates a buffer. Buffers hold data and that's it. "VBO" and "IBO" refer to particular ways of using buffers.

Comment: @immibis yea I understand that now. Actually now that that is cleared up I just have one question, so for each model in view at any given time you have to rebind its ibo before you call glDrawElements correct?

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian The GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding is part of the VAO. If the currently bound VAO has the buffer you want already, then of course you don't need to re-bind it.

Comment: @immibis ok I see so the ibo is automatically bound to the vao that is active when it is created

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian No, it's `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)` that binds it to the current VAO.

Comment: @immibis ok I already have that in my code it it is like I know something but don't think I know it.. well in any case I think understand how all of this works now that I slept thinking about it so thanks for all the help.